# Minted breakautoindent changes behaviour on OverLeaf

Tags: line-breaking, minted, overleaf

I am trying to typeset some of my source code using the minted package, this works fine that is to say there is no outright error but something strange happens why I typeset locally. For various reasons I am unable to use OverLeaf for my project but when I tried this small bit of LaTeX (with a purposefully long line of code added to demonstrate the problem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[frame=lines,fontsize=\footnotesize,linenos=true,breaklines=true,breakautoindent=true]{vb.net}
        Public Iterator Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Thing)) Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Thing)).GetEnumerator
            For Group = 0 To MaxVal
                Yield New NameOfThing
            Next
        End Function
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I got the following different outputs from exactly the same LaTeX:

Output from TeX Live 2014 running on Overleaf:
[image: Output from TeX Live 2014 running on Overleaf]

Output from TeX Works running on Windows 7 64 bit
[image]

Both of these outputs were from LuaLaTeX but pdfLaTeX produces the same result.

**How can I get output like the one from OverLeaf but locally?** (Without changing from TeXWorks to TeX Live if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in `minted` version 2.1 that is breaking `breakautoindent`. For a temporary fix, you can [download version 2.0](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/releases), which works correctly.  Just put the `minted.sty` in the directory with your document.

I will add this to the list of fixes needed in version 2.2, and try to get 2.2 on CTAN by the end of the week.

**Edit Dec 20**: A fixed version is now on [GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/minted). A final version 2.2 will be on CTAN soon.

Comment: The man himself I am honoured! I will roll back to version 2.0 for now as advised and update to 2.2 when you get a chance to upload it. Thank you for your help!